# How should I solve this kind of problem of Arithmetic progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **$x^{n-1} - 2x^{n-2} +3x^{n-3} - 4x^{n-4}  ------------ ± n $ where $n\xrightarrow\ \infty$ and $1>x>-1$**

my attempt

> in the following a normal term at r position from right is in the
>   form of the following.
>       $$T_r= (-1)^{r-1}rx^{n-r} $$
>       then two solutions should be there one is where n is odd then sum is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} T_n$$ where $T_r$ is negative
>
> and another is where n is even then $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} T_n$$ where $T_r$ is positive

what should I do next?

Comment: Should it not be $$T_r=(-1)^{r-1}rx^{n-r}$$?

Comment: Sorry,I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the sum be $S(x)$ and compute $xS(x)+S(x)$. What you get after simplification is

$$x^n-x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}-\cdots\mp x\pm n.$$

The sum of the alternating geometric series is

$$-\frac{x+(-x)^{n+1}}{x+1},$$ which is finite. Then the sum diverges.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works :

Take $x^{n-1}$ common, then we have the sum $ 1 - 2x^{-1} +.......\pm nx^{-(n-1)} $. Now, put $y = x^{-1}$. Then, we get :
$ 1 - 2y+ 3y^2.........\pm ny^(n-1)$. Now, observe that this series is just the derivative of the following geometric series :
$y - y^2 + ........ \pm y^n$.
Now, i hope you can sum it and take derivative wrt $y$.( Sum depends upon the parity of $n$)